# What's the small white plastic dome on old Pentax lenses?

Tags: lens, pentax, old-lenses

My old Pentax lenses have a small white dome between the aperture ring and the focus ring. See the photo below:

[image: smc Pentax-M 1:1.7 50mm]

The clear white dome calls to mind the larger white plastic domes used in light meters, but there's no such thing in this lens (and that'd be a very strange place for one). You can't press it or anything; it's not a button or control. It's just a white plastic bead half-embedded in the metal. It's common to many or most Pentax manual focus lenses (take a look at any of the K or M primes [shown here](http://kmp.bdimitrov.de/lenses/)); I haven't seen it elsewhere.

This dome is on a part of the lens body which does not move. It lines up with f/1.7 when the aperture is set to f/16, or f/2 (unmarked) when the aperture is set to f/22. It's not in a place where it seems likely to provide any meaningful tactile feedback — in fact, when holding the camera in use, I'd characterize it as "out of the way". And it's offset from the orange dot used for mount alignment, so it's not that either.

So, what is it there *for*? It can't be just to look pretty, can it? It's not very pretty.

Comment: My SMC Pentax-A 1:2 50mm has yellow plastic dome.

Comment: I saw that in some pictures, but couldn't tell if it was yellowed white plastic or originally yellow. My f/2 50mm got thrown in a box once I got this one, which is no-contest better. I'll have to dig it out and inspect.

Comment: I'm going to take a random guess that it lines up the mount for putting the lens on

Comment: There is an orange dot used for that, and it doesn't line up with that. But now that you mention it, it _does_ line up with the release lever when mounting or unmounting.

Comment: Pentax calls it: white plastic bump.

Comment: Why so they do! It's right there [in the manual](http://www2.pentaximaging.com/files/manual/KM.pdf)!

Comment: I have a couple of old Ricoh lenses (Pentax mount) that have the same bump. Always wondered what it was.

Comment: on my Pentax SMC 1:1.7 50mm, it looks yellow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-slr-lens-discussion/118354-pentax-f1-7-50mm-question.html) ( and guessed by Dreamager) it is aligned with the lens release button of older Pentax cameras. It's much easier to change the lens in the dark. ( I don't really understand the advantage of the newer orange dots. )

From [K-1000 user's manual](http://www.butkus.org/chinon/pentax/pentax_k1000/pentax_k1000.htm):

> In the dark, when red dots are difficult to see, align the white
>   plastic bump on the lens barrel with the lens release lever by touch.

Comment: Well, okay then. Thanks to both you and Dreamager! :)

Comment: yay for guessing :D

Comment: Manual also available [directly from Pentax](http://c758710.r10.cf2.rackcdn.com/files/support/manual/535_1314745097-1859806433_manual.pdf). Cool.

Comment: @asalamon74 Is the bump fluorescent?

Comment: No, my bump is not fluorescent ( maybe it was 30 years ago ).