# What is the small yellow/white "hemisphere" near the aperture scale on some Pentax lenses?

Tags: lens, pentax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the small white plastic dome on old Pentax lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17247/whats-the-small-white-plastic-dome-on-old-pentax-lenses)

What is the purpose of the small yellow/white "hemisphere" near the aperture scale on some Pentax lenses?

See for example the Pentax M 50 1.4 where the hemisphere is above the 2.8 number of the aperture ring.

[image: Pentax M 50 1.4]

Comment: @mattdm thank you very much! My English is not so good and I did not find it. Shall we close this question?

Comment: Don't delete it — it will be closed as a duplicate and maybe help others who search for the words you used rather than the ones I did in the other question.

Comment: don't delete! My one is distinctly yellow, I could not find the original 'white' answer